# How to push a group of arrays (string format) to an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a group of array from database in this format `[52,16,135],[54,16,140],[22,16,140]` and I need to push all elements of of it into new array separately but looks like my code adding them as an array to the code

[image]

but what I need is

```
[
    "True",
    "52",
    "16",
    "135",
    "54",
    "16",
    "140",
    "22",
    "16",
    "140",
    "Other Value"
]
```

```js
var str = '[52,16,135],[54,16,140],[22,16,140]';
var arr =[];
arr.push('True');
arr.push(str.replace(/\[/g, "").replace(/\]/g, "").split(','));
arr.push('Other Value');
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
var str = '[52,16,135],[54,16,140],[22,16,140]';
var arr =[];
arr.push('True');
arr.push(str.replace(/\[/g, "").replace(/\]/g, "").split(','));
arr.push('Other Value');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy fix to your code will be using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) inside the `Array.push()` method to spread all the elements of the array generated by `split()` as arguments of the `push()` method. Also, you can use one `replace()` sentence `replace(/[[\]]/g, "")` in replacement of the two you have.

```js
var str = '[52,16,135],[54,16,140],[22,16,140]';
var arr =[];
arr.push('True');
arr.push(...str.replace(/[[\]]/g, "").split(','));
arr.push('Other Value');
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add .flat() method to your result. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat`enter code here`

```js
var str = '[52,16,135],[54,16,140],[22,16,140]';
   


var arr =[];
arr.push('True');
arr.push(str.replace(/\[/g, "").replace(/\]/g, "").split(','));
arr.push('Other Value');
console.log(arr.flat());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Just instead of pushing, concatenate.

```js
var str = '[52,16,135],[54,16,140],[22,16,140]';
var innerArr = str.replace(/\[/g, "").replace(/\]/g, "").split(',');
var arr = ["True"].concat(innerArr).concat(["Other Value"]);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `replace`, you could add a `[]` around the string to create a valid JSON of 2D array. Then `parse` the string and use [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

```js
var str = '[52,16,135],[54,16,140],[22,16,140]';
const newArray = JSON.parse(`[${str}]`).flat();
console.log(newArray)
```

ES5 solution if `flat` and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) aren't supported in your browser:

```js
var str = '[52,16,135],[54,16,140],[22,16,140]';
var parsed = JSON.parse('[' + str + ']'),
    newArray = [].concat.apply([], parsed);
    
console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have 2 immediate options I can think of:

First option: [ES6 spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const str = '[52,16,135],[54,16,140],[22,16,140]';
const strArr = str.replace(/\[/g, "").replace(/\]/g, "").split(',');
const  arr = ['True', ...strArr, 'Other Value'];
console.log(arr);
```

Second option: [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```js
const str = '[52,16,135],[54,16,140],[22,16,140]';
const strArr = str.replace(/\[/g, "").replace(/\]/g, "").split(',');
let arr = [];
arr.push('True');
arr = arr.concat(strArr);
arr.push('Other Value');
console.log(arr);
```

I would go with option 1 if that's possible for you.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
['True', ...str.match(/\d+/g), 'Other Value'];
```

```js
var str = '[52,16,135],[54,16,140],[22,16,140]';
var arr = ['True',...str.match(/\d+/g),'Other Value'];
console.log(arr);
```